# Difficulty upgrading the Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

So, I'm trying to upgrade the Android SDK. My current configuration is as follows:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Eclipse Helios
- SDK version 12.

I got far enough along in the process Eclipse to suddenly want version 14, or it won't work. I can't seem to update using the Eclipse update plugin. When I try to manually update the SDK, going to the directory and running SDK Manager, then I update the components. It downloads, says it needs to restart the SDK, and then it restarts. Then it doesn't realize it has just updated anything, and re-downloads it. Repeat 5 times, and you're where I'm at right now. Any ideas as to what I can do?

I should add, I've tried the following.

1. Run SDK Manager as administrator.
2. Change the permissions of the SDK folder to allow for easier writing access
3. Upgrading via Eclipse, and SDK Manager.

Comment: SDK 12 is somewhat old, the current one is 16. I'd say if you have a decent internet connection just grab a fresh SDK from the dev site and start from scratch. This should be faster than figuring out the issues/depencies with the existing one. You can install it in parallel to your existing SDK and change the folder in eclipse if you want to play it safe.

Comment: Also better to keep the old SDK, Eclipse and ADT installation for a while, as android SDK (especially the Android Library Project) has changed rapidly during several recent release (Library Project part started from r14), From many developer's feedback, there are lots of issues when trying to bring legacy project into latest SDK, most of them relate to Library Project design changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out what my problem was, with a bit of help from alextsc's comment.

I think somehow I had both the 32 bit and the 64 bit SDK installed, in 2 different folders (Program Files and Program Files (x86)). I think the SDK was getting confused where to update, and thus wasn't working correctly.

So, what I ended up doing was uninstalling the SDK, re-installing it, ensuring that I have the 64 bit version, and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use administrator account to run Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Tried that, it didn't seem to help. Will edit my answer to reflect that.